# MagicalRecords: Can't save simple relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm new to MagicalRecord so this may be a simple thing but I've looked everywhere for an answer and no one seems to be having my issue.
I have a simple Core Data structure with one Parent leading to many Child object with the relationship children one way, and parent the other.

As expected this works...

```
Parent *parent = [Parent MR_createEntity];
parent.name = @"John";

Child *child1 = [Child MR_createEntity];
child.name = @"Paul";

parent.children = [NSSet setWithObject:child];
// or child.parent = parent;

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
```

I generate a tableview of all the children belonging to one parent, and again this works fine. Clicking on a row takes you to a controller that displays the selected child's details. This controller has two properties passed to it from the table: the Parent the table belongs to, and the Child that was clicked.

I then have a save button for any changes made to the details. It triggers the following:

```
self.child.parent = self.parent;
/*    all the other details of the child  */    
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but I always get this error

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet. with userInfo (null)
2013-05-09 17:30:17.312 NoteMD[37109:c07] __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke21(0x815f750) Unable to perform save: The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.
```

I get the same error whatever I try (such as [self.parent addChildObject:self.child] or using existingObjectWithID to get local versions of self.parent and self.child).

I guess I'm misunderstanding how to set relationships in MagicalRecord but I'm running out of things to try....

EDIT: This is the core data setup. I tried to simplify it above but basically Patient is Parent, and Check is Child (with patient = parent and checks = children).

[image: Core data setup]

Also, in app delegate it is init via

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];
```

Also, if I NSLog self.child, or self.parent in the detail view, both look like the right objects.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your coreData setup

Comment: Instead of setting child to parent, can you try setting parent to child. It's always easier to map the one to one relationship.

Comment: child to parent is the one to one. Each parent has many child via children relationship. Each child has one parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens when trying to make a problem manageable it looks like it's nothing to do with the code I posted. When moving from the parent table view to the parent detail view and then the child table view I used the following predicate to get the list of child

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY parent.id like %@", self.parent.id];
```

It was the ANY that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely saving the wrong context. ContextForCurrentThread: is now deprecated as it doesn't always return the proper context. When you save the wrong context it can look like your saves aren't working. I suggest being explicit with the context you're using in your object creation by using the inContext: parameter and them save that context with the mr_save method

Comment: MR_ ContextForCurrentThread isn't listed as depreciated in the code (and is used liberally throughout the library). I've also tried using MR_defaultContext with no luck. I went back through and every time I pull either a parent or child from the database I use (pseudocode)[MR_fetchAllGroupedBy ..... inContext:MR_defaultContext] but I still get the same error.